# Erasing contents of entity on moving to new screen: iOS7

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an entity with a few attributes. I receive JSON data, parse it and populate my entity with the received data. I want to erase this data when I move to another screen in my app. Could someone please let me know if it is possible? If yes how do I go about doing it?

This is what I have done currently,

```
- (void)fetchLeagueTableData
{
    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"TeamData"];

    NSSortDescriptor* rankSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"rank" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[ rankSort ]];

    NSError *saveError = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&saveError];

    NSError* error;
    self.allTeams = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if(self.allTeams == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Could not fetch Team Data:\n%@", error.userInfo);
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    for (NSManagedObject* curTeam in self.allTeams) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:curTeam];
    }
}
```

I do not know how to delete the records.

Comment: What did you try doing to delete the data? What methods are called on your controller when the screen changes?

Comment: I have updated the post with my current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use `self.allTeams` to populate the table view. So, currently you are fetching the data, going to update the table view and then deleting all of the content from the data store.

What you should really be doing is taking the deletion code:

```
for (NSManagedObject* curTeam in self.allTeams) {
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:curTeam];
}
```

and moving it into another method, like `viewDidDisappear`, so that it is only run when the screen is removed from display.

This isn't necessarily failsafe as the user could terminate the app without closing that screen so you should also check and purge at other times (like before you request new JSON data).

Comment: This works... thanks... now my question how do I make sure that the data gets deleted on exiting the app and I don't see duplicate entries when I reload the app...

Comment: I'll probably have to populate the json data into an array of objects I guess... as I don't need persistency...